# Firebug display of css

Tags: firefox, css, firebug

In the **HTML** > **Computed** tab of Firebug, I used to get the list of user-defined styles, with the different competing values set from different stylesheets, with the overruled ones stricken out. Now I just get a flat list of all the values, irrespective of whether they are default or set by users, without the overridden values, and without the references to the stylesheets and line numbers. What happened? In the menu attached to the tab, I only have **Sort alphabetically** and **Show Mozilla styles** + options relating to colors. Search as I may I cannot find any option or setting to return to the previous setup.

Answer (score 0):

#### Search as I may I cannot find any option or setting to return to the previous setup.

This was caused by [bug #8018](https://github.com/firebug/firebug/issues/8018) in Firebug:

> Using Firebug 2.0.16 the Computed side panel lists all CSS properties under the Other group starting from Firefox 46.0.

It has been fixed in [Firebug 2.0.17](https://blog.getfirebug.com/2016/06/08/firebug-2-0-17/):

> The Firebug team released Firebug 2.0.17. This is a maintenance
>   release ensuring compatibility with latest Firefox releases.
>
> The beta channel on AMO is also updated.
>
> Firebug 2.0.17 is compatible with Firefox 30 – 49
>
> Firebug 2.0.17 fixes the following issues: 8003, 8012, 8018, 8022

Install the latest Firebug to get back the old behaviour of the "Computed" tab.

I can confirm it is working as expected on Windows 7 64 bit, Firefox 47.0.